# Performance difference between POD and non-POD classes

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, register-allocation

I'm struggling to understand why my compilers (g++ 8.1.0 and clang++ 6.0.0) treat POD (plain-old-data) and non-POD code differently.

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct slong {
  int i;
  ~slong() { i = 0; }
};

int get1(slong x) { return 1+x.i; }

int main() {
  std::cerr << "is_pod(slong) = " << std::is_pod<slong>::value << std::endl;
}
```

defines a class `slong` with a destructor (hence not POD) and the compiler, with -Ofast, will produce for get1

```
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        incl    %eax
```

but when I comment out the destructor (so `slong` becomes POD) I get

```
        leal    1(%rdi), %eax
```

Of course the performance issue is minor; still I'd like to understand. In other (more complicated) cases I also noticed more significant code differences.

Comment: Note that the action in your destructor is *pointless*. That `int` is about to cease to exist, who cares what it's value is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `movl` accesses memory, while `leal` doesn't.

When passing a `struct` to a function by value, ABI can stuff it into a register (`rdi`) if it's POD.

If the `struct` is not POD, ABI must pass it on stack (presumably because the code may need its address to call the destructor, access the vtable and do other complicated stuff). So accessing its member requires indirection.

Comment: Ah, OK, so it seems non-POD structs should not be avoided if it's to wrap things like integers.

Comment: I'd say non-POD structs should be avoided exactly because of this! [Zero overhead principle](https://www.quora.com/What-does-zero-overhead-in-C-mean).